# How to use type_traits is_same for std::array

Tags: c++, templates, stdarray

I am trying to write a validation method for a template input, which tests if the input is a `std::string`, `std::vector`, or an `std::array`.
However for the latter I am having an issue as I must provide a constant length for the
type definition.

So when I call `std::is_same<T, std::array<uint8_t, container.size()>>::value` the compiler of cause gets angry (makes sense container.size() is not static). Is there are way to get around this?
I don't know the size of the container in advance and I will never know it :(

```
    template<typename T> bool valid_container_type(const T& container)
    {
        (void) container; 
        if constexpr (std::is_same<T, std::vector<uint8_t>>::value)
        {
            return true; 
        }
        else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, std::vector<char>>::value)
        {
            return true; 
        }
        else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, std::array<char, container.size()>>::value)
        {
            return true; 
        }
        else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, std::array<uint8_t, container.size()>>::value)
        {
            return true; 
        }                
        else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, std::string>::value)
        {
            return true;
        }     
        return false; 
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `container.size()` is not a constant expression and can't be used as non-type template argument.

You can add a type trait to get the size at compile-time (or use [`std::tuple_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple_size) directly as @康桓瑋 [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69493947/how-to-use-type-traits-is-same-for-stdarray#comment122833024_69494119)). E.g.

```
template <typename>
struct get_array_size;
template <typename T, size_t S>
struct get_array_size<std::array<T, S>> {
    constexpr static size_t size = S;
};
```

Then use it as:

```
if constexpr (std::is_same<T, std::array<uint8_t, get_array_size<T>::size>>::value)
```

Note that you have to move the `if` branch for `std::string` before the one before `std::array`. Otherwise you need to define `size` (and give it a default value) in the primary template too.

Comment: huh this is cool

Comment: `rror: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'base64::get_array_size<std::basic_string<char>>'
        else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, std::array<uint8_t, get_array_size<T>::size>>::value)

Comment: I get the above error when trying to use this

Comment: @LarsNielsen You can move the if brance for `std::string` before the one for `std::array`, or adding a default value in the primary template `get_array_size`. E.g. https://wandbox.org/permlink/F46yQbf150CeSAtG

Comment: There is no need to build a wheel since there is already a `tuple_size_v`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if some `T` is an `std::arary` with elements of type `uint8_t` like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct is_uint8_t_array : std::false_type {};

template <size_t S>
struct is_uint8_t_array< std::array<uint8_t,S> > : std::true_type {};


int main() {
    std::cout << is_uint8_t_array<std::array<uint8_t,32>>::value << "\n";  // 1
    std::cout << is_uint8_t_array<std::array<int,42>>::value << "\n";      // 0 
    std::cout << is_uint8_t_array<int>::value << "\n";                     // 0
}
```